# Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 one page checkout not showing paypal payment information

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 and trying to set up the payment method but it's not working.

For example, if I enable `SavedCC` or 'Check or money order' from `Payment Methods` it appears instantly on one page checkout Payment Information TAB. If I select PAYPAL Website Payments Standard  eigther with

```
1. website payment standard
2. express checkout
```

or both, on one page checkout nothing appears on Payment Information TAB and if you click continue button you get the following error.

> Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment
>   methods available for it.

I couldn't figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Have you made sure it is setup all the way? There is a special PayPal section to do most of the configuration for PayPal.

Comment: yes i am talking about same section

Comment: i figure out what was problem. if you are using base currency which is not supported by palpal, you will not get these options.

Comment: @air:if you found answer your self.please post your detail answer that may help others

Answer (score 0):

The paypal payment method will not appear in one page checkout.

It was happened to me when I am using AED as base price.